# DFS traversal in directed graph in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to print a graph traversal with starting `vertex 0` which covers all the nodes and "directed from" vertices should be visited before "directed to". I explained my question below with expected output. Here is the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    int vertex;
}node;

node *G[20];   
//heads of linked list
int visited[20];
int n;
void read_graph(); 
//create adjacency list
void insert(int,int);  
//insert an edge (vi,vj) in te adjacency list
void DFS(int);

void main()
{
    int i;
    read_graph();
    //initialised visited to 0

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        visited[i]=0;

    DFS(0);
}

void DFS(int i)
{
    node *p;

    printf("\n%d",i);
    p=G[i];
    visited[i]=1;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
       i=p->vertex;

       if(!visited[i])
            DFS(i);
        p=p->next;
    }
}

void read_graph()
{
    int i,vi,vj,no_of_edges;
    printf("Enter number of vertices:");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    //initialise G[] with a null

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        G[i]=NULL;
        //read edges and insert them in G[]

        printf("Enter number of edges:");
           scanf("%d",&no_of_edges);

           for(i=0;i<no_of_edges;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter an edge(u,v):");
            scanf("%d%d",&vi,&vj);
            insert(vi,vj);
        }
    }
}

void insert(int vi,int vj)
{
    node *p,*q;

    //acquire memory for the new node
    q=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    q->vertex=vj;
    q->next=NULL;

    //insert the node in the linked list number vi
    if(G[vi]==NULL)
        G[vi]=q;
    else
    {
        //go to end of the linked list
        p=G[vi];

        while(p->next!=NULL)
            p=p->next;
        p->next=q;
    }
}
```

It is traversing all the nodes, Output :-

```
Enter the number of vertices : 6
Enter the number of edges : 6
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 0 1
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 1 2
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 0 4
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 4 5
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 2 3
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 5 3

It is giving output :- 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

But, if we look closely, `(u, v) = (2, 3)` and `(u, v) = (5, 3)`  we are visiting 3 before 5. 5 also directed to 3. 
My expected output should be :- `0 4 5 1 2 3` where we are visiting each vertices and also visiting `u` before `v`

I only understand C and prefer solutions to be in C language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A total order that maintains the edge relation is called a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  You can get a topo sort with a DFS that visits all the vertices in **post-order**.  But the post-order is the **reverse** of what you want.

Your code visits nodes in **pre-order**: It prints each node before visiting its children. So move the `printf` down to the point *after* the children have been searched.

The reverse of the printed order will have the property you want.

If you need to print the correct order, then, for example, you can push the nodes on a stack as you visit them. After the search is complete, pop and print until the stack is empty.

Answer (score 0):

According to me your code implementation is correct, basically you graph looks like this

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3
 \            /
  4 -------> 5
```

So your output of 0,1,2,3,4,5 is also a correct output for DFS approach but if specifically you want your solution to be 0,4,5,1,2,3 -> then your input order for setting directed graphs should be in this format

```
Enter the number of vertices : 6
Enter the number of edges : 6
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 0 4 
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 4 5
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 0 1
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 1 2
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 2 3
Enter an edge (u, v) :- 5 3

It should give output as 0,4,5,1,2,3
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, but when I am using (1 2) (1 3) (2 5) (3 4) (5 6) (4 6) , by using DFS(1)  it is giving output (1 2 5 6 3 4), which is not expected

Comment: why not, so in this input your graph will look like this right: 1->2, 2->5, 5->6, 1->3, 3->4, 4->6, so my dfs would go this route and you will get the output: 1,2,5,6,3,4 which is correct, make a sketch on a piece of paper and you will understand

Comment: Hi, I understand, DFS is correct here. But, is there any way, where I can check if u is visited before v in (u, v), if not visited then start the loop again. In this order, I can traverse a graph where u is visited before v in (u, v)

Comment: I can tell you a simple way to check whether u was visited before v or not, keep a global int counter = 0 and keep a map<int, int> vertex_visited, as you enter DFS() make counter++ and vertex_visited[s] = counter, so in this way the vertex which has less counter value means it was visited before the current vertex... I hope you are getting my point

Comment: Hi, I am confused here to check for visiting node and start the loop again. I appreciate your help. A small example, will be good for me to understand.

Comment: you can do something like this:-   int counter=0; int visited_count[20];   void DFS(int i)
{
    node *p; visited_count[i] = counter;
   counter++;
    printf("\n%d",i);
    p=G[i];
    visited[i]=1;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
       i=p->vertex;

       if(!visited[i])
            DFS(i);
        p=p->next;
    }
}

Comment: So for each node you have the count and the one which has less value at visited_count that means it was traversed before right, so you sort by that value and print them...something like that, I guess

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong tool. A Depth-First Search does *not* necessarily visit "directed from" before "directed to".

Here's an algorithm that will do the job:

First, use DFS (or any other search) to construct a list of vertices reachable from the starting vertex. Do this *silently*, print nothing.

Then find a vertex V in the list such that there is no edge from a vertex in the list to V, print V, and remove V from the list. Repeat this step until the list is empty.